# how to get multiple collection data in single get method using mongoose in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
  router.post('/user', function (req, res) {
      try {
        MongoClient.connect("mongodb://test123:test123@localhost:27017/test", function (err, db) {
          db.collection('user').findOne({ _id: req.body.UserId }, function (err, founddata) {
            if (err) {
            } else {
              if (founddata) {
                db.collection('project').find({ userId: founddata._id }, function (err, data) {
                  if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                  } else {
                    console.log(data)
                  }
                })
              }
            }
          })
        })
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
      }
    })
```

I have tried  many  time  but i geting error for second  query is not run.output is  null value.

Comment: What is the error? If the error is only null, I guess it's because `founddata` can be an empty object since query by _id normally require ObjectID on the query.

Comment: Get  Null .  I  am  converted _id String to  ObjectId  .then  also  getting null value

Comment: How  `{ _id: req.body.UserId }` is? somethink like `{ _id: mongodb.ObjectId(req.body.UserId)}`

Comment: Hey  ...  my  first  Query  is  perfectly  run and getting output  second Query  is getting  null value   ...like  this            mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.UserId)}